# Does Super Saiyan benefit melee?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I have a pure melee saiyan.

Does transforming to super saiyan benefit me at all? e.g. will it make me my basic attacks hit harder? take less damage? be faster in attack or movement?

I couldn't observe anything, unless maybe speed; I think I fly faster but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's about a 2%-5% increase to basic attacks from going SSj, and you take 10% less damage, so yeah, going super is a benefit in the least.

You'll just have to figure out if sustaining SSj is worth the extra increase for you over a different build.

[GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805627-dragon-ball-xenoverse/71403677)

Answer (score -1):

It does, however it is a very slight increase
Try [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/323470/discussions/0/612823460261277959/) Steam Thread

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for this?

Comment: Yes see this Steam Thread http://steamcommunity.com/app/323470/discussions/0/612823460261277959/

Comment: I'd recommend adding that to your answer.  A single sentence answer, without a source or method of testing doesn't tend to lend a lot of credibility to your answer.